# create-react-app R14 (Memory Quota Exceeded) on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

More or less only applicable to beginners...

First time deployment of application on Heroku and received the following errors after using the standard Heroku Deploy instructions in the Heroku Dashboard:

```
2017-05-10T21:43:59.732215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=543M(106.1%)
2017-05-10T21:43:59.732277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

Heroku Deploy Instructions:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that I was deploying the application as it is in the dev environment, which WOULD cause a significantly larger memory use. My thinking is that it would be running the entire dev environment on Heroku...

Instead, you need to build the application and deploy that (static) version of the application. This is done using the following!

[Create-React-App Deployment](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)

And adding this buildpack to the Heroku. Instructions on site:

[create-react-app buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)

I have no idea how this actually works.

Comment: Just to shortcut this, the commands you need to run to update the buldpack are...
```heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack mars/create-react-app
```
This will overwrite your existing project configs if you already have a heroku config set up for this project (which is what you want).
After running the command above, I just pushed to heroku...
```git push origin master
```
After the push, I waited 5 minutes for the DAP to update, and everything worked. 
 Good Luck!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. I figured out the app on Heroku was running in the development environment.

Fixed it by:

1. Installing the `serve` package (Run `npm install serve -g`)
2. Changing the `start` script to `"start": "serve -s build"`

You also need to add the script to use for dev environment, just a normal tract script start (`"dev": "react-scripts start"`)

So, my scripts look like this:

```js
    ...
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
    ...
```

Comment: You also need to install serve locally to be included in the dependency for heroku, otherwise it will not work. npm install --save serve

Comment: This solved my trouble. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! I was thinking I had built a bloated app for a second. Fixed it with ease.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm using Express and React in the same application, so I have to build react and then start the express server. I was not aware that heroku runs the `build` script before running the `start` script, so I initially put my build script in my start script which caused the out of memory issue.

The problem:

```json
"start": "npm run build && npm run start:server"
```