# Application error on webpage running, was fine earlier

Tags: reactjs, heroku

This is making my day crazy. I have a React.js page and a Java spring boot backend both deployed through Heroku.

My React.js was running absolutely fine till I made some display changes and some coding logic when file gets uploaded, so nothing related to memory use during display of homepage. I have Github connected to it, so last deploy was sucessful but on opening the page get "Application Error".

On checking log tails I am getting

```
2024-02-14T20:48:56.232065+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2024-02-14T20:48:56.232114+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-02-14T20:48:56.337438+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2024-02-14T20:49:10.263965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=625M(122.0%)
2024-02-14T20:49:10.266612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2024-02-14T20:49:28.398259+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=nige-dashboard-ebe5b010ecec.herokuapp.com request_id=a83c0256-5fcb-42f8-936c-54113fecefef fwd="117.233.188.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2024-02-14T20:49:28.923431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=783M(153.0%)
2024-02-14T20:49:28.925645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2024-02-14T20:49:49.988472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=772M(150.8%)
2024-02-14T20:49:49.990602+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2024-02-14T20:49:58.778951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nige-dashboard-ebe5b010ecec.herokuapp.com request_id=d3d16fa7-52af-4f86-a3e0-2e77b32d7295 fwd="117.233.188.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2024-02-14T20:50:10.464690+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=1362M(266.2%)
2024-02-14T20:50:10.488272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
2024-02-14T20:50:10.490961+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2024-02-14T20:50:10.743042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=nige-dashboard-ebe5b010ecec.herokuapp.com request_id=a449cb24-df21-4582-8e22-34a5d20f39a0 fwd="117.233.188.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19874ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2024-02-14T20:50:10.814563+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2024-02-14T20:50:10.851626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2024-02-14T20:50:16.710021+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nige-dashboard-ebe5b010ecec.herokuapp.com request_id=aa1e7c6f-c4fa-464e-a377-5a809414ec02 fwd="117.233.188.137" dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am continously getting R14 and R15 error of memory quota exceeding

Assuming I might have messed up with new code, I created a new branch on Github and used the last commit that was running ok and deployed again from heroku, still same error on project that was running fine.

I have restarted dynos, deleted project and created again but still no change.

Any help please !

PS: every commit runs perfectly locally

Comment: If your React code is generating memory issues you're definitely deploying it wrong. React should be compiled to static JavaScript as part of its build process. There should be close to _zero_ memory used when serving it up. "Starting the development server" is a problem: it's for development _only_. Please show us your `package.json` (at least the scripts section) and, if you have one, your `Procfile`. (Side note: Heroku is a poor choice for hosting things like this. It isn't designed for static site hosting. You might be better off deploying your front-end and back-end together.)

Comment: It was working fine since last 1 year of deployment in various stages of production. I solved it and have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling stumbled upon this answer

[StackOverflow Answer on my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765687/create-react-app-r14-memory-quota-exceeded-on-heroku)

So in summary the issue is its deploying the complete development environment on server thereby increasing memory.

2 part solution:

1. Installing the serve package (Run npm install serve -g)
2. Changing the start script to "start": "serve -s build"

Suddenly why it started behaving like this, no idea !